# Python directory list returned to Django template

Tags: python, list, directory-structure

Total Python newb here.  I have a images directory and I need to return the names and urls of those files to a django template that I can loop through for links.  I know it will be the server path, but I can modify it via JS.  I've tried os.walk, but I keep getting empty results.

Comment: then show how you use os.walk() or show some of your code

Answer (score 2):

If your images are in one directory

```
import os
root="/my"
Path=os.path.join(root,"path","images")
os.chdir(Path)
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files[-3:].lower() in ["gif","png","jpg","bmp"] :
         print "image file: ",files
```

Comment: Extensions aren't always 3 chars, might be better to do files.split('.')[-1].lower() so you can include variations like jpeg

Comment: better still: os.path.splitext()

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single directory, `os.listdir('thedirectory')` will give you a list of filename strings that seem to be suitable for your purposes (though it won't make "the urls" -- not sure how you want to make them?).  If you need a whole *tree* of directories (recursively including subdirectories) then it's worth debugging your failed attempts at using `os.walk`, but it's hard for us to spot the bugs in code that we're not shown;-).